# Backbonejs - CORS error

Tags: backbone.js, cors

I have a REST service sitting at `http://restservice.net`. I am implementing a client for this service in backbone. The client is simply an html file (for bootstrapping the application) and bunch of js files holding my backbonejs code. I am hosting these files on another site `http://client.net`.

My backbonejs code is calling into `http://restservice.net` but now allowed due to `same origin policy`. I have already looked at other SO questions that talk about how I can only talk to `http://client.net`.

Do I have to redirect every request through `http://client.net`. I see that as inefficient. What's the point in using a client side MVC framework then? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does `restservice.net` support JSONP?

Comment: It is my service so I can make it support `JSNOP` but then how  to make `Backbonejs` work with `JSONP`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options: JSONP and CORS both of these demand that your `http://restservice.net` server is setup to suppor the protocols. Forcing backbone to use JSONP simply requires you passing an option to `Backbone.sync`. One way to do this is like this:

```
sync: function(method, model, options){   
   options.dataType = "jsonp";  
   return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);  
}
```

The problem with JSONP is that you can only make GET requests, so your REST api is effectively read only. To get CORS working you simply need to configure your api server to send back the proper headers  . This would pretty liberal:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE OPTIONS
```

[here is a pretty good run down](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) on CORS. If you set that up, then things will pretty much work as usual.

If you don't have the ability to make changes to the server at `http://restservice.net` then you have no choice but to proxy all the requests to that service. This is definately inefficient but implementing is probably simpler than you would expect. One thing to consider is a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)

Comment: Just add that to support `JSONP` you have to make changes in the format of your response you can't respond any more with a _pretty_ and _clean_ JSON but with a _dirty_ javascript function call. I really will move to `CORS` always that is possible.