# No requests made when saving/creating Backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

This is stumping me... whenever I do model.destroy() the request goes through successfully and the model gets deleted.

However, whenever I try to model.save() or collection.create(this.model) no requests are being made to the server for some reason.

Trying to see if there are any errors with:

```
this.collection.create({ title: 'some title' }, {
  success: function (model) {
    console.log(model);
  },
  error: function (model, response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

And all I get is this in console:

```
Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}
```

My models:

```
Stuff.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'http://domain.com/api/stuff'
});

Stuff.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Stuff.Model,
    url: 'http://domain.com/api/stuff'
});
```

Any idea on why this might be happening? Thanks

*Update -- just checked console on Chrome and it says:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com/api/stuff. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Comment: Maybe problem happens on "this.collection", check what "this.collection" is.

Comment: Look up CORS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422695/backbonejs-cors-error